# How can I fill a small tapered gap between my pavers and a step?

Tags: pavers

The sidewalk project needs few finishing touches.

I need to fill the gap between the house and the pavers to lock them before going over with vibrating plate.

The gap is 1.5", but the steps at the entrance don't have straight angle and the gap there goes up  to 3.5"

[image: Gap]

I don't think putting slivers of pavers in it will make it look better.

What are my options? I was thinking about pebbles but don't feel like they will prevent pavers from traveling. Should I use concrete? And maybe cover the it with pebbles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just lay the carpet or rubber sheet on the pavers (not attached) and use the vibrator.

As for the sidewalk being lower than the dirt by about 4-5 inches, you could put in a retaining wall/edge, or make a box planter into an edge (a french drain may be helpful, here), or shape the soil so that it diverts/drains away into a swale (aka a ditch).

To help keep pavers put (because you're worried about pea gravel in the sliver), use paving edger:

[image]

For the concrete idea, here's a couple of videos: [Pebble inlay in concrete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AB9YPbFsLw) and [Stone pebble mosaic ideas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yCuaW_Rfb0). Another method involves simply [exposing aggregate](http://www.dcs-ks.com/product_images/Exposed_aggregate_finishes_for_decorative_concrete.pdf) by basically washing off the surface of the concrete.

Comment: I got the edging installed on the side that's facing the dirt the site wouldn't let me post more than one picture :)

Good point about the drain, been discussing it today with my friend. 

For the sliver I think I'm going to use gravel (compacted with piece of wood) and dark polymeric sand on top. The pebbles are bound to escape and get everywhere. 

That's a big piece of carpet, not sure where to find that :) Thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: @DmytroBazulin you don't need a big piece of carpet... something about 4' - 6' square or round should be pretty convenient. Just move it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Pavers cut to fit is the right approach. All over the world there are municipal sidewalks and streets and this is how it's done, often with elaborate, curving patterns.

If you'd rather not do that for whatever reason, fill it with concrete or pea gravel or whatever's on hand. The pavers won't move. It's going to accentuate the area, though, unless you cover it with a mat or something.

Comment: You are right about the patterns, but everywhere I read the expansion joint is recommended between the house and the pavers. So the slivers would be extremely thin (1/2 inch) and I don't think it's much better look than just wider joint. I think I have an idea with gravel/polymeric sand sandwich. Thanks for pitching in in any case!

Comment: Once you deduct the thickness of the expansion strip (1/2"?) you still have  over 2-1/2" at the thick end. That's not a "sliver" in my book.